# Sistema de Loja Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Olá. Preciso de uma maneira de criar uma loja de carros em um jogo no unity.
Comecei a criar a loja, porém não encontro uma maneira de mostrar o carro comprado em outra cena, ou seja, o jogo saber que você comprou aquele carro.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CarShop : MonoBehaviour {

public string carroSelected;
public Text velMaxima;
public Text Acele;
public Text cambio;
public Text Motor;
public Text preco;
public Text nome;
public Text carroaviso;
public GameObject confirmar;
public GameObject semDinheiro;
public GameObject efetuada;
//public GameObject capContorno;
//public GameObject copContorno;
//public GameObject viaContorno;
//public GameObject nviaContorno;
public float dinheiro;
public float precoCarro;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    velMaxima.text = "0 km/H";
    Acele.text = "0s";
    cambio.text = "0 Marchas";
    Motor.text = "NULL";
    dinheiro = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("dinheiro");
    nome.text = "Selecione um carro";
    preco.text = "";
    carroSelected = "";
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    precoCarro = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("precoCarro");
    if(dinheiro >= precoCarro)
    {
        preco.color = Color.green;
    }
    if(dinheiro < precoCarro)
    {
        preco.color = Color.red;
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("CarroAtual", carroSelected);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("dinheiro", dinheiro);

}

public void sim()
{
    Bought();
}

public void nao()
{
    confirmar.SetActive(false);
}

public void Buy()
{
    if(dinheiro >= precoCarro && carroSelected != "")
    {
    precoCarro = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("precoCarro");
    confirmar.SetActive(true);
    carroaviso.text = nome.text;
    }
    if(dinheiro < precoCarro && carroSelected != "")
    {
        semDinheiro.SetActive(true);
        Invoke("semD", 3f);
    }
}

void semD ()
{
    semDinheiro.SetActive(false);
}

void Bought()
{
    //Carro Comprado
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    //Capital
    if(carroSelected == "Wolk Capital")
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("ultComprado", "Wolk Capital");
    }
    //Copa
    if(carroSelected == "Wolk Copa")
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("ultComprado", "Wolk Capital");
    }
    //Viagem
    if(carroSelected == "Wolk Viagem")
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("ultComprado", "Wolk Capital");
    }
    //Novo Viagem
    if(carroSelected == "Wolk Novo Viagem")
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("ultComprado", "Wolk Capital");
    }
    //===========================================================

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("carrosSLOT", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("carrosSLOT") + 1);
    if(dinheiro >= precoCarro)
    {
        spend(precoCarro);
        confirmar.SetActive(false);
    }

}

void spend(float amount)
{
    dinheiro = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("dinheiro");
    dinheiro -= amount;
    efetuada.SetActive(true);
    Invoke("efD", 3f);
}

void efD () 
{
    efetuada.SetActive(false);
}

public void capitalSel () {
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("precoCarro", 3000);
    precoCarro = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("precoCarro");
    carroSelected = "Wolk Capital";
    nome.text = carroSelected;
    velMaxima.text = "110 km/h";
    Acele.text = "21.90s";
    cambio.text = "4 Marchas";
    Motor.text = "Boxxer";
    preco.text = "3000R$";
    //capContorno.SetActive(true);
    //copContorno.SetActive(false);
    //viaContorno.SetActive(false);
    //nviaContorno.SetActive(false);
}

public void copaSel () {
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("precoCarro", 8000);
    precoCarro = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("precoCarro");
    carroSelected = "Wolk Copa";
    nome.text = carroSelected;
    velMaxima.text = "170 km/h";
    Acele.text = "10.3s";
    cambio.text = "5 Marchas";
    Motor.text = "AP (Alta Performance)";
    preco.text = "8000R$";
    //capContorno.SetActive(false);
    //copContorno.SetActive(true);
    //viaContorno.SetActive(false);
    //nviaContorno.SetActive(false);
}

public void viagemSel () {
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("precoCarro", 11000);
    precoCarro = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("precoCarro");
    carroSelected = "Wolk Viagem Super";
    nome.text = carroSelected;
    velMaxima.text = "170 km/h";
    Acele.text = "11.5s";
    cambio.text = "5 Marchas";
    Motor.text = "AP (Alta Performance)";
    preco.text = "11000R$";
    //capContorno.SetActive(false);
    //copContorno.SetActive(false);
    //viaContorno.SetActive(true);
    //nviaContorno.SetActive(false);
}

public void nViagemSel () {
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("precoCarro", 40000);
    precoCarro = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("precoCarro");
    carroSelected = "Wolk Novo Viagem";
    nome.text = carroSelected;
    velMaxima.text = "190 km/h";
    Acele.text = "10s";
    cambio.text = "5 Marchas";
    Motor.text = "Power EA";
    preco.text = "40000R$";
    //capContorno.SetActive(false);
    //copContorno.SetActive(false);
    //viaContorno.SetActive(false);
    //nviaContorno.SetActive(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Cara uma maneira que você pode trabalhar com isso é criando um script em um Gameobject separado e nele você utilizar o método DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject) passando como parâmetro esse gameObject. Nesse script também você terá uma variável do tipo GameObject que terá o carro escolhido na compra e então no start é só você recuperar esse valor e instanciar o carro.

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversas maneiras para preservar dados, aqui vão algumas sugestões:

**Classe PlayerPrefs**

```
int valor = 1;

// para gravar
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("valor_exemplo", valor);

// para obter o valor
valor =  PlayerPrefs.GetInt("valor_exemplo");
```

[Documentação PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

**Outra solução:**

Use a função [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) para perservar um objecto e todos os seus componentes para a proxíma cena.

Ex: `DontDestroyOnLoad(objecto_loja);`

**Utilizar um ficheiro**

Também pode utilizar um ficheiro para gravar e ler valores e assim conseguirá manter os valores após o encerramento do programa.

[Veja este artigo](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000341143-How-do-I-read-and-write-data-from-a-text-file-).

Answer (score -4):

To create a car store in your Unity game, you need to create a system that saves the information of the car that the player has purchased. One way to do this is to use PlayerPrefs to store the car information and access it in another scene.

In your CarShop script, you can use PlayerPrefs.SetString to save the name of the car that the player has purchased. For example, in your Bought() function, you can add the following line of code:

PlayerPrefs.SetString("carSelected", carroSelected);

Then, in your other scene where you want to access the purchased car information, you can use PlayerPrefs.GetString to retrieve the name of the purchased car. For example, you can add the following line of code to your other scene:

string carSelected = PlayerPrefs.GetString("carSelected");

This will allow you to access the name of the purchased car and load its information in the new scene.

You can also use PlayerPrefs to save other information about the purchased car, such as its price, speed, and acceleration. Just make sure to use unique keys for each piece of information to avoid conflicts with other PlayerPrefs keys in your game.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua resposta? Caso prefira, você também pode responder perguntas em inglês no [site Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com).